# Nested array pagination in mongodb using mongo repository in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I am trying to do pagination for array in my document using mongo repository only in spring boot but not able to find proper solution
Code in Spring boot

```
    {
        "_id": "objectid",
        "userId":01
        "cars": [
            {
                "carDetails":{
                    "model": "Bentley",
                    "year": 1973
                },
                "location": [45.123, 47.232],
                "companyDetails":{
                   "companyName":"abc",
                   "companyCode": 056
                 }  
            },
            {
                "carDetails":{
                      "model": "Rolls Royce",
                      "year": 1965
                 },
                "location": [5.123, 7.23],
                "companyDetails":{
                   "companyName":"xyz",
                   "companyCode": 90
                 }  
            }
        ]
    }
```

above is my document structure
I just want to do pagination on car arrays
tried code but not working as expected

```
    public interface userRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
     @Query(value = "{'userId'=?0}", fields = "{'car': 1}")
     List<User> findUserId(int userId, Pageable page);
    }
```

I have classes for user, cars, companyDetails, carDetails and location

```
In user.class
private ObjectId _id;
private int userId;
private List<cars> cars;

In cars.class
private CompanyDetails companyDetails;
private List<Location> location;
private CarDetails carDetails;
```

In other classes contain respective fields,
don't want $slice and aggregate concept I have already implemented but I just want to use mongo repository with pageable , Query DSL or any other way to may custom repository to achieve it.

Thanks in advance